# ROW_NUMBER() over partition by [DateCol vs 1] order by DateCol

Tags: t-sql, row-number, partition-by

Im pretty new at T-SQL.

I saw this T-SQL script:

```
   SELECT [Date], ClosePrice, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by 1 order by [Date])rn 
   FROM NIFTY_SMALLCAP_250_STOCKS
```

source: https://youtu.be/vE8UcS8U_xE?t=2882 (with my own small change)

Works as expected:
[Expected result (and sample data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HYUV.png)

Then I changed the script to : **[Date] instead of 1**

```
SELECT [Date], ClosePrice, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Date] order by [Date])rn 
   FROM NIFTY_SMALLCAP_250_STOCKS
```

The Result - all "dynamic" rn column values equals 1
[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUi0P.png)

***My question:***
Why partitioning by [Date] (that is obviously uniqe) doesnt work here?

What am i missing here about the "ROW_NUMBER()" and "partition by" combination?

Comment: `PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date]` doesn't make a lot of sense, in truth; the ordering will therefore be completely arbitrary. Sample data and expected results will help us help, you.

Comment: Why is the ordering "tied" to partitioning?

Comment: What do you mean? It's isn't, per say, but the ordering will restart for each distinct value in said partition, so ordering and partitioning on the same expression(s) results in arbitrary ordering (in that partition).

Comment: I think I get it now. In the first script the Frame/Window consists of all rows and for each row in the select stmt, ROW_NUMBER() is being called within that Frame.

Comment: That isn't how Stack Overflow works.